# UnboundLocalError inside python function replaced with NameError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nameerror

Basically I was receiving `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pw_is_long' referenced before assignment` and saw using the `global` keyword helps to get rid of this inside a function. After using it, I am getting `NameError: name 'pw_is_long' is not defined`

I'm working in selenium and the instagram website. This code worked before I put it inside the function.

My first function:

```
password = input("Password\n")  
def pw_minimum_length(pw):
        if len(pw) > 5:
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
        
pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)
```

My second and main function:

```
def login(username, password):
    #some if-else code
    #selenium element selecting & clicking
    #the following is the heirarchy inside the function where I am having this issue
    while (condition):
        if (condition):
            password = input("Password\n")
            global pw_is_long #when this line was not here, I was getting UnboundLocalError
            pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)
        while not(pw_is_long): #line throwing NameError
            print("Password length must be at least 6 characters")
            password = input("Password\n")
            pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)
```

Any answers are helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: If we are just looking at your code, `pw_is_long` is simply won't exist all the time on the instance where the `if` block is not executed; that causes the `NameError`.  The `UnboundGlobalError` is simply because `pw_is_long` is also not found at the global scope.

Comment: @metatoaster but since I'm creating ```pw_is_long``` after the first function, ```pw_is_long``` should still be recognized as a variable right?

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: A name can only be referenced after it has been created, not before.

Comment: good rule: all `global` put at the beginning of function. This way everone will know that you use external variable which can makes problems. If you don't need this variable outside function then better create it at the beginning of function and assign some default value - ie. `pw_is_long = None`

Comment: `pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)` (assignment) happens before `while not(pw_is_long):` (use); without `global`, `pw_is_long` will be local since it's assigned; assigning a local before it's used is exactly what the error complains about. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: As for the `NameError` when using `global`, I can't reproduce it with anything like this setup. A `global` can't run conditionally; it doesn't "run" separately at all. The global statement doesn't directly translate into bytecode; instead it affects the compilation of the rest of the function, statically. While it's poor style to put it inside an `if`, that has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If `condition` is `False` then it doesn't run `if condition` and it doesn't create variable `pw_is_long = ...` but you need it in `while not pw_is_long`

I see two possibilities:

First: create `pw_is_long` at start with some default value - ie. `None` or `Flase` or `0`

```
def login(username, password):

    pw_is_long = False

    while condition:
        if condition:
            password = input("Password\n")
            pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)
            
        while not pw_is_long:
            print("Password length must be at least 6 characters")
            password = input("Password\n")
            pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)
```

Second: maybe you should rather nested it and run `while` inside `if`

```
def login(username, password):

    while condition:
        if condition:
            password = input("Password\n")
            pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)
            
            while not pw_is_long:
                print("Password length must be at least 6 characters")
                password = input("Password\n")
                pw_is_long = pw_minimum_length(password)
```